# Editing Java class file

Tags: java

I have a simple program, say:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("**Welcome message one** ");
    }
}
```

I have compiled this class and edited the content in HelloWorld.class and I changed **Welcome message one**  in .class file to **Welcome message two**.
When i executed HelloWorld.class in command prompt i got error.

So my question is how java compiler identifies the changes in the .class file?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please tell us how you ran this file, and also what the exact error message is.

Comment: Are you saying you edited the `class` file?

Comment: I am also surprised ,Is it so that you edit .class file?

Comment: @this_is_om_vm  this was one of the interview question

Comment: 'I got error' is not a problem description, and 'this was one of the interview questions' is not an answer to 'is it so that you edited .class file?' Try again.

Comment: yes?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's one answer to two questions, and the other one has been asked twice and then repeated by me.

Comment: However it is now obvious that the answer is 'yes', which then leads to the next question: why are you editing .class files? and what led you to expect that the result would remain executable? It doesn't. You should have edited the source code and recompiled it. What you did is not valid.

Comment: I told it was an interview question. Even I thought of trying it once.. No one edits .class,even I know

Comment: But you didn't say so until pressed, four times. And 'how java compiler identifies the changes in the .class file?' is meaningless. It doesn't. It detected the corruption of the file, by noticing that the version fields were invalid, exactly as stated in the exception. Stupid question, wherever it may have come from.

Comment: Sorry for that. So where it maintains the version? In my case it gave some version number 8243.8224.

Comment: Prasad read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: Thank you.. I lost lot of my reputation because most of the people downcasted the vote.

Comment: @Vicrobot : This is someones question.Not mine.

Comment: Firstly this question was posted by you. Secondly whoever asked this was may be tricking you because the error that occurs when you format the class file is ClassFormatError. You should first give a try to your  questions and then post here.

Comment: I tried it and then i posted the question here. I was trying to know the reason or may be specifications behind it

Answer (score 1):

One does not simply edit a .class file. Consider them to be completely final. If you want to change something about how it runs later, save a separate file with your changes that this class then reads and acts upon.

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-bufferedreader-class

---

If this was just a test to try to modify someone else's finished project, you want to use a decompiler first. I would suggest the built in decompiler in intellij since it is easy to use.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend that you also read [Locke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285687/9773761), as directly editing class files is generally a bad idea.

However, if you want to know why the edit you made might have prevented the code from running, read on.

### How the Error Occurs

There's not enough detail in your question to know exactly what happened, (e.g. you didn't specify how you edited the `.class` file).

First of all, the compiler isn't detecting anything. In fact, as @EPJ points out in his comment, the compiler doesn't even run in this scenario after initially creating the `.class` file. The problem, in my test, was caused by my text editor, [Atom Text](https://atom.io/).

Atom automatically interpreted the file as though it were encoded using UTF-8. It would have done this because .class files use an encoding *similar* to UTF-8, however, it is slightly different to UTF-8.

Now, Atom is smart enough that it will try 'fix' some problems in the data it reads, so that it can still display the file contents for you. This means that when I edited the string, and saved the file, Atom wrote something slightly different to what it read in, and this made the file invalid for a Java class file.

When I did it, I got the following exception:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class HelloWorld
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file HelloWorld
```

This Magic Value refers to a special value that appears at the beginning of every Java Class file. The value should always be `0xCAFEBABE` in hexadecimal (base-16), and spells the words 'Cafe Babe'. However, my editor instead saved `0xEFBFBDEF`.

See these links for more information on file/character encodings and class files:

1. [Character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) for more information on character encodings.
2. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
3. [Java Class files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

Comment: The paragraph starting 'it appears' is nonsense. 1. The compiler has not been involved since the original compilation, and was not executing when the exception was thrown. 2. How could it (or the JVM) detect changes? 3. Why on earth *should* either of them do so? The fact is simply that the editing process corrupted the file. Nothing more to it whatsoever.

Comment: I thought it was worthwhile address that aspect of the question. However, your comments are certainly more direct on that, and I've updated my answer to be closer to them.